# Cauchy-Crofton formula for different measures

Tags: probability, geometry, integral-geometry

The [Cauchy-Crofton formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crofton_formula) gives the Euclidean length of a curve as an expected number of intersections with random lines. Those random lines have to be distributed according to a measure that is invariant under rigid motions.

I read that a generalization of the C-C formula gives the Riemannian length of a curve under the same conditions; the measure then has to be invariant under the "natural measure on the space of geodesics." What does this mean?